# How do I ensure there's only one observation per row per several columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have this code that separates delimited values from each of the right 3 columns and makes them into separate rows. However, I want there to be only one observation per the 3 rows while keeping the rest of the variables the same.

```
data %>%
  select(Name, A, B, C) %>%
  separate_rows(A, B, C, sep = ";") %>%
  filter(!is.na(A) | !is.na(B) | !is.na(C))
```

As an example, here's a table that demonstrates what I want the function to do.

Input (after above code is run):

| Name | A | B | C |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 |  | 2 |  |
| y |  | 3 | 4 |  |

Desired output:

| Name | A | B | C |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 |  |  |  |
| x |  |  | 2 |  |
| y |  | 3 |  |  |
| y |  |  | 4 |  |

I have been trying to find a function that can do this to no avail. Does anyone know what I can use to do separate values from multiple columns to new rows?

Comment: Please check your example input & output? There is no `y` in the example input and the column names in the output do not obviously correspond to the inputs.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: My bad, every time I try to make a table it won't let me post it because it thinks it's code. There is supposed to be a y in the example input, I will fix that.

Comment: @shadow6810 Did you have a look at my solution below?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following could work:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("x", "y"),
                 A = c(1, NA),
                 B = c(NA, 3),
                 C = c(2, 4))

library(tidyverse)
df |> 
  pivot_longer(-Name) |> 
  filter(!is.na(value)) |> 
  group_by(Name) |> 
  mutate(id = 1:n()) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  arrange(name) |> 
  pivot_wider(values_from = value,
              names_from = name) |> 
  arrange(Name, id) |> 
  select(-id)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Name      A     B     C
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 x         1    NA    NA
2 x        NA    NA     2
3 y        NA     3    NA
4 y        NA    NA     4
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `bind_rows` from dplyr. Something like the following:

```r
df_A = df %>% select(-B,-C) %>% filter(!is.na(A))
df_B = df %>% select(-A,-C) %>% filter(!is.na(B))
df_C = df %>% select(-A,-B) %>% filter(!is.na(C))

output_df = bind_rows(df_A, df_B, df_C)
```

The method is:

- Make multiple versions of the dataframe
- For each one throw out the unwanted columns
- Filter to ensure the wanted column contains a value
- Stack the multiple versions together into a single dataframe

The approach makes use of `bind_rows` instead of `rbind`, because `bind_rows` will combine dataframes based on variable name (`rbind` combines variables based on column position).

Comment: Apologies if it was not clear, but this doesn't work for my case because I have other rows (not every row will have a value in A, B, or C) and columns that need to be preserved

Comment: As I do not have your exact context, I usually try to demonstrate a general approach that can be adapted. I have made some edits that should make it more straightforward for you to apply to your situation.